# JSDoc: How to do correct documentation of functions

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I've some problems to understand the correct usage of JSDoc.

This is an example of simple functions, which I'm using in my project via `import { capitalizeFirstLetter, timestamp } from '/imports/module/functions.js'`

In my first attempt I created the docs and the functions are just listed in a huge list of all classes and functions. 
So I tried to use `@namespace` as shown below. But I am not sure, if this is the correct way.

Maybe someone can give me some help how this simple example should be documented in a correct way.

**/imports/module/functions.js**

```
/**
 * @fileoverview  API: Functions
 * @namespace General Functions
 */

/**
 * Capitalize first letter of a string
 * @function
 * @memberOf General Functions
 * @param   {string}   string
 * @returns {string}
 */
const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => {
  return string ? string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1) : ''
}

/**
 * Get current timestamp in miliseconds
 * @function
 * @memberOf General Functions
 */
const timestamp = () => {
  return Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
}

export {
  capitalizeFirstLetter,
  timestamp
}
```

Comment: It's no clear what's your problem. Is the generated documentation wrong, are functions missing? Please add the _expected and actual_ results. A textual description and/or screenshot of the generated documentation would be nice too. Or does the generated documentation not matter at all (now and in the future)? Don't miss http://usejsdoc.org/

Comment: @try-catch-finally I think my basic problem is, that I do not know when or why to use `namespace`. In this basic example there is a bundle of functions and I want to get them also bundled in the documentation. These functions should not be listed with any other functions of the application